# Fatal error : unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value while retrieving the data from Firebase

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

Hello all m retrieving the data from firebase but m getting the error I don't understand from where its coming coz while printing out it giving me the data but when it comes to retrieve into label its giving me the error.Hoping for the help.thanks.

[Database Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ai1i0.png)

**code :**

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class ProfileViewController: UIPageViewController 
{
    @IBOutlet weak var profileimageview: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var displaynameText: UILabel!

    var databaseref:DatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       databaseref = Database.database().reference()

       if let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
        databaseref.child("profile").child(userID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let dictionary = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

            let username = dictionary?["username"] as? String ?? "username"
            print(username)
            if let profileImageURL = dictionary?["photo"] as? String{

                let url = URL(string: profileImageURL)

                URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                    if error != nil{
                        print(error!)
                        return
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.profileimageview.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    }
                }).resume()
            }
            self.usernameText.text = username
            self.displaynameText.text = username

        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
    }

}

}
```

**here's my console : **note** youandme is the value that I printed out**

```
youandme
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

**getting this error at**  :

```
self.usernameText.text = username

self.displaynameText.text = username
```

Comment: First check whether the username is nil or not by using `guard let usernameRetrived = dictionary?["username"] else { /* Handle nil case */ return }`

Comment: @KarthikeyanBose hey thanks but have already checked its not nill please read my question carefully have already attached the code of my console and youandme is my value.

Comment: A few things; PLEASE include snippets of your structure as TEXT, no images. If we need to use it in an answer we would have to retype it. Secondly, A question. Is that ALL of the data in your Firebase database or is there more than just the one node. Thirdly, As a suggestion, you may also want to move away from NSDictionary and define it as [String: Any] to be Swiftier. Another issue; you are attempting to access the "photo" child where in the database it's "Photo" (note caps)